# Process builder entry criteria trouble

Tags: force.com, formula, process-builder, entry-criteria

I have an approval process with the below entry criteria. 
I played with it multiple times as I was having issues firing it off at the wrong times until I switched it to what you see, however now it dosent work at all.

```
AND(
[Account].Account_Manager__c != null,
[Account].Date_Account_Manager_Changed__c != null,
TEXT([Account].Account_Manager_Assignment_Status__c) != null,
TEXT([Account].Account_Manager_Assignment_Status__c) = '7 Days',
OR(
ISCHANGED([Account].Account_Manager__c.Id  ),
ISCHANGED([Account].Date_Account_Manager_Changed__c),
ISCHANGED([Account].Account_Manager_Assignment_Status__c)
)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some optimizations:

```
AND(
[Account].Account_Manager__c != null,
[Account].Date_Account_Manager_Changed__c != null,
TEXT([Account].Account_Manager_Assignment_Status__c) = '7 Days'
)
```

1. Removed: `TEXT([Account].Account_Manager_Assignment_Status__c) = '7 Days',` as it was redundant with the `=7 days` being there
2. Remove the OR conditions
3. In your criteria ensure that `Do you want to execute the actions only when specified changes are made to the record?` is set to true

This means that if a record is:

- Inserted: it will fire if Manager != null, Managed_Changed != null, AND Status = '7 Days'
- Edited: It will only fire if the values are changed to meet the criteria and they were not meeting the criteria before the edit